# Searching book using Google Data API

Tags: java, android, android-layout, gdata-api

I'm developing an application in which user can search for a specific book and read it and purchase it. I want to use GData book search API for that. Can anyone tell me in which format I will get response as well as how to send request for book search? I have seen GData documentation, but not getting much ideas. Please help me.

Comment: I think that the [gdata documentation](http://code.google.com/apis/books/docs/gdata/developers_guide_protocol.html) is actually pretty good and well explained. If you cannot understand it, this activity maybe out of your league. Try asking something more specific.

Answer (score 3):

You are going to have to send an HTTP `GET` request [as seen here](http://code.google.com/apis/books/docs/gdata/developers_guide_protocol.html#SearchingForBooks). That will return some xml that you will have to parse. Each book is an `<entry>` with lots of items and `<link>`s to things such as a thumbnail of the book's cover, like this:

[image]

All the information that you really care about though, will be sent after that, and will be in an item that has a `dc` prefix on it, such as `<dc:title>Pride and Prejudice</dc:title>`

You really should just be [reading the documentatio](http://code.google.com/apis/books/docs/gdata/developers_guide_protocol.html)n though, because it will be more thorough than anyone on here will care to be.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use feed parser for this . Hit this URL in your IE and see the response. It will return feed. You just need feed parser to parse this and show in your application.

[Google Books Feeds](http://www.google.com/books/feeds/volumes?q=love&min-viewability=partial)

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Java than you should use official [Google APIs Client Library for Java](http://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/).

Here are detailed docs hot to [use it with Google Books](http://code.google.com/apis/books/docs/gdata/developers_guide_java.html).

NOTE 1: Google Books API provides book search, but does not provide access to content. For this you must use [Embedded Viewer API](http://code.google.com/apis/books/docs/viewer/developers_guide.html). This is a Javascript only API so it must be used inside a browser. If you plan to use it with Android you will most probably need to use the [embedded WebView](http://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview.html) which can show HTML and Javascript.

NOTE 2: Commercial books can be searched with Google Books, but they must be purchased before they are available in users library. AFAIK there is no API to purchase books.

Comment: hey...thanks for suggestion..i m able to read book in android device based on embedded viewer..but my problem is that content is too small...i have to press zoom button to read content...do u have any solution to read book..